# Can I use remote database for rackspace cloud server?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, rackspace-cloud

We previously had a company setup our website on a web host and they set it up on a rackspace cloud server (unmanaged). It is an expression engine website.

I have now rebuilt the website into Wordpress but cannot figure out how to setup the database on rackspace. There isn't a database setup on rackspace now, so I'm not sure how the EE site is setup.

I am wondering... Is it possible to just load the wordpress files on the Rackspace server, then connect the Wordpress site to a remote mysql database hosted on Hostgator?

If so, does someone know a a tutorial to do this?

I'm clueless when it comes to uploading a database on Rackspace via SSH. I'm familiar with phpmyadmin but not good with unmanaged servers.

Any suggestion what would be the best for my needs? For now, I need to get the site up and running on Rackspace until I can get a managed dedicated or VPS server setup.

****UPDATE****

I have tried to change the DB host in the Wordpress config file to the IP address instead of localhost, but no luck. Any ideas? This is part of the wp-config.php file in the root directory. I have removed the values. I've tried the hostname like this also with no luck... XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:3306

```
    // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
    /** The name of the database for WordPress */
    define('DB_NAME', 'remote_DB_name');


    /** MySQL database username */
    define('DB_USER', 'remote_DB_user');


    /** MySQL database password */
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'hiddenpassword');


    /** MySQL hostname */
    define('DB_HOST', 'XXX.XXX.XX.XXX');
```

Comment: My first suggestion is to contact their support staff... They will more than likely give you a prompt response. However, if you want to manage your server in the meantime, you could install mysql and mysql-server on your cloud server, then point your wp-config db settings at localhost. That will at least get you up and running.

Comment: Here is how to connect to your cloud server from the command line: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/secure-shell-ssh Here is how you can install your database server on CentOS: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-mysql-server-on-centos Installation procedures will vary between linux distributions. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with Wordpress but it should be possible to have your wordpress site running on a Rackspace Cloud Server connect to a database that is not on Rackspace.

According to http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Configure_Database_Settings, there should be a file named `wp-config.php` in the base directory of your Wordpress site. You should be able to edit the values of the constants starting with `DB_` to configure database connection settings. Specifically, you will want to change the value of the `DB_HOST` constant to be the hostname or IP address of your database server that is not on Rackspace.

Comment: I have tried this with no luck. I have updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Normally wordpress allows different database server and can connect it with different servers. But here it seems problem is not with connection settings you use. You have to give proper permissions for your IP to the database server.
Please check and add permissions to your IP on database server using your credentials

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* To 'dbusername'@'XXX.XXX.X.XX' IDENTIFIED BY 'dbpassword';
```

Check these option with your database administrator and try configuration again 
Reference :

[Wordpress database COnfigurations](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Configure_Database_Settings)

Comment: Where is this line added? The wp-config,php file?

Comment: @MattDuncan This is while logged into mysql as root or a user with that level of permissions. Read my comments. Then, read this: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-wordpress-on-centos-56 How did you go about installing WordPress?

Comment: @MattDuncan  You can do this by login into your mysql console using putty or ssh. Also note one thing don't give host as "localhost". Giive your IP address there

Comment: I think I found the issue. The company that setup their original site and the rackspace hosting closed Port 3306. Trying to figure out what port is being used.

Answer (score 0):

While it may or may not be possible to connect to a Hostgator database from a Rackspace server (contact their respective support departments for details), I know one thing for sure: It's a bad idea anyway. Don't do it.

When they're being used for web applications, MySQL database connections are *highly* sensitive to latency. Each MySQL query performed by your application will be slowed down by at least the round-trip time — for instance, if there is a 10 ms latency between your web server and database server, and your application performs ten MySQL queries for each page load, your page load will take a minimum of 100 ms (10 ms x 10) more than it would without that latency. Ten queries and 10 ms is a best-case scenario, too; many web applications will use considerably more queries than that, and two distant servers may have a round-trip time much higher than 10 ms (100 ms wouldn't be unusual for a transcontinental connection).

Use a local database. If you don't know how to get one on Rackspace, ask their support team!